# Activation required on each restart

Tags: licensing

Mathematica has suddenly begun to ask for the registration key on each restart. I was able to generate a new key already 3 or 4 times, but needed to go through customer service for the latter instances.

The last time it happened, I had completely uninstalled the program, deleting the directories recommended here: https://support.wolfram.com/12473?src=mathematica . After initial startup and entering the reset activation key, the program started. I then closed the program, and was successfully able to restart without being asked for registration again. However, once I rebooted the machine, Mathematic requested the registration key again.

Customer service has made not constructive suggestions how to resolve this. What could be the issue?

System: 2017 MacBook Pro with Intel Core i7 running macOS 12.3.1.

Comment: What has customer service suggested?

Comment: This is probably best left for tech support.  But I would guess your MathID is changing after each reboot.  If you moved those directories out of the way, you could look that up in your password file.  The original location is ~/Library/Mathematica/Licensing/mathpass.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB. Customer support has now escalated to their tech team in the US. They have provided me with a bit of logging software and asked me to run the software, restart, run again and submit the log. I'll post the outcome of this once I have it.

Comment: Thanks @ihojnicki. What you describe is exactly what the tech team now is suggesting as cause. Will update with the outcome of the investigation.